# CSS select content to print (media query)

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to build a print media query to print only specific contents of the screen:

```
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class='printed-content'>
  <p>
    PRINTED CONTENT
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}

@media print {
  body {
    display: none;
  }
  .printed-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

When I print, the printed content is now being printed (all remains empty). I´m sure I´m missing some simple, but I can´t find out what.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yyyjgyqk/)

Comment: When you have `body { display: none; }` everything inside is not displayed... and since the `.printed-content` is inside the `body` -it will not be displayed.

Comment: Humm... How to solve it then ? Should a put an outer div on whole content with display:none ?

Comment: div{display:none} .printed-content{display:block}

Comment: Thanks @iSZ. That work in one level. What if I have divs inside divs and some inner divs are printable and others are not, does printed-content will overwrite all divs {display:none} ?

Comment: No, it will not. The inner element of `display: none` will not be displayed. You can wrap the "main" div with a `display: none` in print version and it will solve your problem.

Comment: If you have .printed-content class on everything that you want to be shown in print view you can do something like this to hide everything else: `*:not(.printed-content){ display: none; }`

Comment: div{display:none} .printed-content{display:block} .printed-content > div{display:block}

Comment: @chaduhduh: Not working. See fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r1qp5skq/1/)

Comment: @Mendes check my comment for the answer

Answer (score -1):

To hide all elements that do not match your selector you can use the :not() psuedo class.

As @Dekel noted you would want to scope this appropriately such as:

```
@media print {
    body .wrapper *:not(.printed-content) {
        display: none;
    }
    body .wrapper .printed-content * {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will set `display: none` to the `body` and all other main `div` elements.

Comment: @Dekel: His HTML doesn't contain any body or wrapping containers, but I think you have a valid point that needed clarifying.

Comment: Every document have a `body` element, even if it is not part of the above example. The `*` selector will be applied to that `body` element as well.

Comment: @Drekel: Good point I updated answer with more info to reflect that. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Drekel.. Not working - it is printing the full content. Check the JSFildde [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yyyjgyqk/1/)

Comment: @Mendes: See updated code. I thought the initial code would work but apparently it does not.